# is separating update column in other table will help in optimization(MySQL MyISAM table)?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, query-optimization, myisam

MySQL MyISAM "**Table1**" having **70% select** , **13% update** and **0.67% insert** statements approximate.

There is one "**count_column(int)**" which used to increase count with primary key.(Update statements)

Updating of "**count_column**"  make table select queries in **"Waiting for table level lock"**

So separating "**count_column**" in other table will reduce  **"Waiting for table level lock"** or not?

I also need separated column in select statements with join.

Thanks, Yogs

Comment: explain me something, count_column = to counter? how is that?.

Comment: What about the remaining 16.33% of statements? Can they safely be ignored?

Comment: (16.33%) Can they safely be ignored? YES

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK your locking problem is the COUNT with INSERT, not the UPDATE itself - but you must have a huge bunch of SELECTs. Your question is lacking quite some details...

COUNT is really optimized on MyISAM tables, if you encounter problems with that you maybe should consider a count estimate or memory tables holding this value:-\ But an exact row count is stored for MyISAM that is extremely quick to get by the storage engine, so you maybe even slowed down MySQL with your solution. "Slow" COUNT is valid for engines like InnoDB because of their transactional nature.

One other thing to consider is, that storing a count in a column in the table itself is an additional column for each row and quite bad.

And if you are using triggers to accomplish that you should be aware of http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-12 :)

Answer (score 1):

Moving the frequently updated cells in another table will greatly reduce number of locks on the table and speed up select on it. Converting the table to InnoDB also can help (if you are not using full-text indexes, they are still not supported in MySQL 5.5 InnoDB), since it uses row-level locks instead of table-level. If you have a lot of queries, take a look at [this article about implementing efficient counters](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/07/01/implementing-efficient-counters-with-mysql/)